# WampServer's alternative php version not working

Tags: php, wamp

I recently updated my Window's wamp version to the latest (64bits & PHP 5.4). It works fine. But then i tried to install the PHP 5.3.1 extension. When i try to use it, Wamp stops on orange and never starts. PHP 5.4 works just fine. This is the first time I try a dual version setup with Wamp. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you cheked if the event-viewer reports anything?

Comment: Didn't even know about this program! The error is this: `The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 127 of C:/Program Files/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.1/php5apache2_2.dll into server: The Apache service named n\xe3o \xe9 um aplicativo Win32 v\xe1lido.     .`

Comment: Does the .dll file exist in the path given? Are there alternatives to that dll files? Have you tried editing the httpd.conf?

Comment: There is probably a dependency issue in the dll's for 5.3.1 vs 5.4. I would stick with 5.4 unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Skype, change the configuration. It seems that Skype also uses the port 80.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! It would be helpful if you included some instructions for which settings in Skype to change and how to do it. Complete answers are more likely to be useful and less likely to be downvoted.